# How to make a function returns the right value?

Tags: c, arrays, function

I wrote this function which finds the longest sequence in an array and it is supposed to return length and where did the sequence began.

How can I make *begin point to the first largest (longest) sequence it encountered?

```
int longestSequence(int a[], int n ,int* begin)
{
    int oldlength=1,length=1,i,maxvalue=0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(a[i+1]==a[i])
        {
            length++;
            if(length>oldlength)
            {

                oldlength=length;
                *begin=i;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            oldlength=length;
            length=1;
        }
```

Comment: Save `i` in the `else` case and then assign it to `*begin` in the inner `if` case.

Comment: The longest sequence of *what*?

Comment: @kaylum I should put a spot=i in the else case and leave *begin where it is?

Comment: @WeatherVane ones and zeros.

Comment: Think about what info has been given to you and just try what you think it should be.

Comment: "point to the first largest (longest) sequence". I've seen others ask this question before (same assignment I guess). So I know what you mean. But it is not clear for others. You mean - start *index* of longest sequence, right?

Comment: @Pizzatags that is not what the code does. It is trying to check for equal consecutive numbers, not zeroes and ones specifically. Aside: you have array overflow: `for(i=0; i<n; i++)` should be `for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)` since you index at `[i+1]`.

Comment: @WeatherVane correct sorry for the wrong answer there

Comment: @kaylum yes I guess its a popular question when teaching pointers,I did mean the index when the sequance started and if there are two of the same length keep the first one I will edit the post.

Comment: Rephrasing and changing your question after receiving 2 answers that answers the original is bad SO etiquette.  Rolling back the post.

Comment: @chux I hope one I wont break any rules and guidlines in my posts

Comment: @Pizzatags Learn as much as able from this post.  You could always post another question as needed, but I suspect you can find similar posts too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make `*begin` point to the first largest sequence it encountered?

To make `*begin` point to something, `*begin` must be a pointer and `begin` must be a pointer to a pointer.

Pass in the address of the caller's `int *begin`, so `longestSequence()` should receive a `char**`

```
int longestSequence(int a[], int n ,int** begin) { 
  ...
       *begin = &a[i];
  ...
  return length;
}

// call
int *call_begin = NULL;
int length = longestSequence(a, n, &call_begin);
```

Answer (score 0):

To modify the `*begin` pointer in this function you need to give his own adress

I mean u need to get an `int **` instead of your simple pointer

The new prototype gonna be : `int longestSequences(int a[], int n, int **begin)`

```
int longestSequences(int a[], int n, int **begin)
    {
         for(i=0; i<n; i++)
         {
            if(a[i+1]==a[i])
            {
                length++;
                if(length>oldlength)
                {
                    oldlength=length;
                    *begin= &(tab + i); //(which is equivalent to &tab[i]
                }
            }
           else
            {
                oldlength=length;
                length=1;
            }
    }
```